# How to pass an argument to a method using typescript and arrow function?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i have code like below,

```
const getColumns: (
    canRead?: boolean) => ColumnWithId<Data>[] = canRead => [
        {
            Header: 'Name',
            id: 'name',
            Cell: props => {
                return (
                    <div>{props.value}</div>
                );
            }
         },
     ]
 ];
```

Now i want to pass another argument mode to the getColumns method

```
const mode = someMode === 'read'; 
const columns = getColumns(canRead, mode);


const getColumns: (
    canRead?: boolean, mode: boolean) => ColumnWithId<Data>[] = canRead, mode => [
        {//error in this line
            Header: 'Name',
            id: 'name',
            Cell: props => {
                return (
                    <div>{props.value}</div>
                );
            }
         },
     ]
 ];
```

It gives error cannot find name 'canRead' and cannot find name 'mode'. I am not sure how to pass these arguments to the getColumns method and why i see these errors.

i am new to using typescript and arrow functions. can someone please help me with this. thanks.

Comment: You're not using `mode` anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to surround the arguments with parenthesis:

```
const mode = someMode === 'read'; 
const columns = getColumns(canRead, mode);

const getColumns: (canRead?: boolean, mode: boolean) => ColumnWithId<Data>[] = (canRead, mode) => [
        {
            Header: 'Name',
            id: 'name',
            Cell: props => {
                return (
                    <div>{props.value}</div>
                );
            }
         },
     ]
 ];
```